# Is there a way of finding which app is already using a specific keyboard shortcut? (macOS Big Sur)

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, google-docs

I would like to use the Google Docs shortcut for inserting a page break ⌘ + Enter. It doesn't work, and I have no idea which (or if another) app is using the shortcut. I can't even find it with Cheatsheet. The Google Docs menu even confirms that ⌘ + Enter is the shortcut for a page break.

[image: Screenshot showing Google Docs menu]

Comment: I don't have Big Sur running here, but imagine it's similar to Catalina in this respect: have you reviewed all the entries in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts, going through each of the categories in the left column?

Comment: I have. I found that I apparently had used the shortcut elsewhere in the settings menu, however, the shortcut still doesn't work. No clue why.